# Sticky Nav Bar Jumps To Top

Tags: jquery, css, navigationbar, sticky, jquery-waypoints

I have a sticky navigation bar (using waypoints) that jumps too soon when scrolled.

The bar does not continue to smoothly scroll all the way to the top point, but rather jumps a couple pixels when it nears the top of the screen, which in turn reveals the background content as well (not what is needed in any way).

I tried looking at other fixes posted but can't seem to get the fix to work for mine.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Look for margins or padding on the relevant elements. Those are often the cause of these small jumps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to me to show up only whe the nav menu is not active( when header lacks **.active-menu** class). So, my solution would be to set the initial set of the nav to active and , after it passes the folding point with 10px, lets say, to make it collapse. In such way you will have the effect you wan and the whole awesome site *(I consider it great - 9.8 out of 10)* would be bugless.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I go about doing this? I found that the issue lies within the display of the nav (as I'm also using an offcanvas nav) but if I assign display:none the ease-in transition no longer fires. So with that, I think your fix may be best suited.

Comment: Any fiddle code or even a zip with a download link would be sufficient for me to help. If you like the answer, +1. Thank you.

Comment: If you can't +1, accept the answer. The mail valpraim@gmail.com. I'll see what I can do untill tomorow.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I managed to address the issue by positioning and display. Thanks for your help though!